# Javascript split with random content inside it

Tags: javascript, split

I wan't to use split a string with javascript, because I wan't to delete some text a serval times. De value of the string is:

```
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="margin-top: 10px;">
        <tr>
            <td><img src="img/pb_read.gif" alt="Oud" /></td>
            <td><a style="overflow: hidden; display: block; width: 195px; " title="Re: One2xs host: Starter" href="read_pb?id=353544">Re: One2xs host: Starter</a></td>
            <td><div style="width: 90px; overflow: hidden;"><a href="http://www.one2xs.com/profiel/bekijk?gebruiker=julianh">Julianh</a></div></td>
            <td>12-11-2011 07:46:22</td>
            <td><input style="margin: 0;" type="checkbox" name="berichten_check[]" value="353544" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="img/pb_read.gif" alt="Oud" /></td>
            <td><a style="overflow: hidden; display: block; width: 195px; " title="Re: Starterhost" href="read_pb?id=353376">Re: Starterhost</a></td>
            <td><div style="width: 90px; overflow: hidden;"><a href="http://www.one2xs.com/profiel/bekijk?gebruiker=jidde">Jidde</a></div></td>
            <td>11-11-2011 16:19:22</td>
            <td><input style="margin: 0;" type="checkbox" name="berichten_check[]" value="353376" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="img/pb_read.gif" alt="Oud" /></td>
            <td><a style="overflow: hidden; display: block; width: 195px; " title="Transactie geweigerd" href="read_pb?id=353248">Transactie geweigerd</a></td>
            <td><div style="width: 90px; overflow: hidden;">one2xs</div></td>
            <td>10-11-2011 19:53:24</td>
            <td><input style="margin: 0;" type="checkbox" name="berichten_check[]" value="353248" /></td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

I want to delete `<td><input style="margin: 0;" type="checkbox" name="berichten_check[]" value="******" /></td>` every time, but the `value` is a random code with 6 numbers. How can I delete every line with that condition with split?

I'm very sorry for my bad English, but I hope you will understand my question.

Comment: Parse that string into the DOM. It's easier to work with it that way (because in the DOM the above string becomes an object tree which you can traverse, etc.)... **Edit:** I see you want to remove the last TD from each row - that's an easy task in the DOM (especially if you use a library like jQuery...).

Comment: What's `wan't` a negation of??

Comment: Btw, HTML source code manipulation is not something what you want to do with JavaScript inside the browser. You want to do such operations on the server-side *before* sending the HTML source code to the browser... JavaScript is good for manipulating object structures like the DOM - string manipulation is not one of the strengths of JavaScript...

Comment: I have copied the html elements from the page source from another website and I put it into a variable.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a string, use the `replace` function, in conjunction with a Regular expression:

```
string = string.replace(/<td><input style="margin: 0;" type="checkbox" name="berichten_check\[\]" value="\d+" \/><\/td>/g, "");
```

If the element has already been appended to the HTML, use:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByName("berichten_check[]");
for(var i=elements.length-1; i>=0; i--){
    var cell = elements[i].parentNode;
    cell.parentNode.removeChild(cell);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With DOM:

```
var container_ = document.createElement('div');
container.innerHTML = html;

var inputs = container.getElementsByTagName('input');

for(var i = inputs.length; i--; ) {
    var cell = inputs[i].parentNode;
    cell.parentNode.remove(cell);
}

html = container.innerHTML;
```

Comment: Consider `[].forEach.call( inputs, function ( input ) { ... });` instead of `for` statements. I like it because (1) it doesn't require an iterator variable, (2) it creates a new scope so you can use local variables inside the iteration body, (3) the current value is referenced by the first argument (`input` in this case) so you don't have to access it via `inputs[i]` or put it in a variable if you need it more than once.

Comment: Sure it does - with [ES5-shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim). No-brainier... `:)`